# External user authentication integrated to LDAP for authorization only

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, authorization, one-time-password

I'm integrating an external OTP solution to be used along LDAP(Active Directory/Open LDAP). The user registers the token using userid and password which are authenticated against LDAP, upon successful validation the user is enrolled in the OTP system with token id and user id.

LDAP process during Registration:

- Bind to ldap.orgname.local:636 (server) with SSL with account "CN=ServiceUser,DC=orgname,DC=local" (serviceUser) and password "svcPassword" (servicePassword)
- Search the tree at root "OU=Users,DC=orgname,DC=local" (userRootDN) for user entry with "cn" (userNameAttribute) equal to "john"
- Find an entry at "cn=john,OU=Users,DC=orgname,DC=local"
- Authenticate  "cn=john,OU=Users.DC=orgname,DC=local" with password "testpass"
- If authentication is successful, OTP token is associated with user “john”

During authentication, user provides userid and OTP from the token, the OTP system validates the OTP from the token and userid, if matched has to query LDAP to retrieve the groupmember/nsrole to provide right access rights in the system.

LDAP process during Authentication:

- Perform LDAP lookup for authorization after a successful authentication by a matched OTP token.
- Bind to ldap.orgname.local:636 (server) with SSL with account "CN=ServiceUser,DC=orgname,DC=local" (serviceUser) and password " svcPassword " (servicePassword)
- Search the tree at root "OU=Users,DC=orgname,DC=local" (userRootDN) for user entry with attribute "cn" (userNameAttribute) equal to " john"
- find an entry at "cn=john,OU=Users,DC=orgname,DC=local"
- Search the tree at root "OU=Roles,DC=orgname,DC=local" (roleRootDN) for group entry with attribute "member" (roleUserDNAttribute) equal to "cn=john,OU=Users,DC=orgname, DC=local"
- Return the value of the "cn" (roleNameAttribute) attribute for each role to continue giving access rights to the user

Since getting the role is a query only, At this point is there any LDAP command or methods to lets the LDAP know that the user has been authenticated externally which will be helpful for auditing logs?